# Why is there "the" in "The organic acids are weak in the sense that this ionisation is very incomplete."?

Tags: articles

From [Chemguide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/basicorg/acidbase/acids.html#top):

> **The** organic acids are weak in the sense that this ionisation is very incomplete. At any one time, most of the acid will be present in the solution as un-ionised molecules.

The author speaks about organic acids in general, not about some specific group of organic acids. Why then he uses the definite article?

Wouldn't it be better this way:

> Organic acids are weak in the sense that this ionisation is very incomplete. At any one time, most of the acid will be present in the solution as un-ionised molecules.

Comment: It's a simple, unobtrusive way of indicating that the discussion is moving from consideration of acids in general to organic acids in particular.

Comment: @StoneyB - thank you! So "the organic acids" is still a generic noun phrase here, despite the 'the'. Interesting.

Comment: The 'definite' article is so called because it puts a boundary (L *finis*) around the term it marks: the author carves out the organic acids from the larger group of acids for consideration.

Comment: Thank you, @StoneyB. I never thought of it that way. Your comment makes perfect sense to me now. I *always* appreciate and learn from your comments and answers. With kind regards,

Comment: "... the author carves out the organic acids from the larger group of acids for consideration." - this line made me imagine and understand the point completely. This is something new. Thanks!

Comment: +1  for @stoneyB's comment. Another way of looking at it is that, if you are talking about **all** members of a group- for example, the big cats, the Americas, the Florida keys, the Joneses, you are talking about a definite group, so you can use 'the'.

Comment: One wonders why the author did not use *the* before *organic acids* in two prior occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The organic acids are represented as a known group or set of chemicals here. Because there is only one such set, the author can use the definite article in this sentence. Everybody understands which set we are talking about.